# EhCache Configurations seems not to be working

Tags: spring, ehcache

I have an ehcache xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ehcache>
     <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />
     <cache name="oddscache"
               maxElementsInMemory="1000"
               timeToIdleSeconds="5"
               timeToLiveSeconds="5"
               overflowToDisk="false"
               memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
 </ehcache>
</xml>
```

and my method:

```
@Override
    @Cacheable("oddscache")
    public void cacheOdds(String id) {
        String url = "https://api.betsapi.com/v1/bet365/start_sp?token="+ token +"&FI="+id;
        System.err.println("This method is executed !!");

        String val = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        System.err.println(val);
```

Of course the method will execute once, and the succeeding calls will just return values from cache. But it seems that after the cache is expired (5 seconds in this case), the method is still not executing and just returning values from cached.

[image]